# Selection of QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: c++, database, qt, user-interface

In this function im trying to connect each QTreeWidgetItem with its corresponding query,
once i select an item a Dock widget that has a query result in tableview model is shown.

what i want is that when i select a new item the shown dock widget hide and  new one appears with a new result. what i have until now is that each item i select a new Dock widget appears . I want to see only one dock widget.

here is my function

```
void MainWindow::DocumentTable()
{
tableview = new QTableView;
query = new QSqlQueryModel(this);

foreach(it,treeWidget->selectedItems())
{
    for (int col=0; col< it->columnCount(); ++col)
    {
        qDebug() << col << it->text(col);

QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("select * from document where Folno=:Folno");
qry.bindValue(":Folno", it->text(col));
qry.exec();

query->setQuery(qry);

    tableview->setModel(query);
tableview->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
tableview->show();

Docwidget= new QDockWidget(this);
Docwidget->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);

Docwidget->setWidget(tableview);
addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea,Docwidget);
Docwidget->show();


if(!query->submit())
  {
     qDebug() << "Error " << query->lastError().text();
  }

 db.close();

}
}
   }
```

any ideas ??  :)

Comment: I am afraid I have problems understanding what exactly is it that you want to do. Also, the code does not seem relevant to the actual "click-show" part

Comment: in brief, what i want when a new widget appear the old one disappear.

Comment: You will need to manually remove the widget from MainWindow's children and hide/delete it before creating new one.

Comment: Thank you very much Zeks for you help.. but what do you mean by removing it manually??

Comment: I do not entirely remember how qobject system works, you might have to google it a bit, but if it does try to delete ALL of its children(it remembers every qobject that was created with it as a parent) on program exit then if you delete older dockwidgets yourself you will have a double deletion on your hands.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're after, but here's my contribution:

Add a line after:

```
query = new QSqlQueryModel(this);
```

then, add this:

```
QDockWidget * lastDockWidget = NULL;
```

Add:

```
if (lastDockWidget != NULL)  // If no null, then
    lastDockWidget.hide();   // hide it, delete it, or whatever...
```

before

```
Docwidget= new QDockWidget(this);
```

and this:

```
lastDockWidget = Docwidget;
```

right after:

```
Docwidget= new QDockWidget(this);
```

Result:

```
void MainWindow::DocumentTable()
{
tableview = new QTableView;
query = new QSqlQueryModel(this);
QDockWidget * lastDockWidget = NULL; // This was added

foreach(it,treeWidget->selectedItems())
{
    for (int col=0; col< it->columnCount(); ++col)
    {
        qDebug() << col << it->text(col);

QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("select * from document where Folno=:Folno");
qry.bindValue(":Folno", it->text(col));
qry.exec();

query->setQuery(qry);

    tableview->setModel(query);
tableview->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
tableview->show();

if (lastDockWidget != NULL)  // This was added
    lastDockWidget.hide();   // This was added
Docwidget= new QDockWidget(this);
lastDockWidget = Docwidget;  // This was added
Docwidget->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);

Docwidget->setWidget(tableview);
addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea,Docwidget);
Docwidget->show();


if(!query->submit())
  {
     qDebug() << "Error " << query->lastError().text();
  }

 db.close();

}
}
   }
```

Hope it helps.